# Ball squeeze through pipes

Tags: animation, physics, workflow, cloth-simulation, soft-body

I am trying to make simulation similar to this (around 5sec)
https://www.pinterest.es/pin/573997915020314265/

[image]

and i have this issue that the ball wont come trough the pipe like on the picture. Any idea how to make it work?

[image]
[image]

Comment: did u try shape keys?

Comment: A *Cloth* sim + a *Force Field* or an inner collision sphere works for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxesU.gif - give the ball some pressure and uncheck *Single Sided* in the settings of the collision object

Comment: Thanks it works i had to increase force of Force Field and disable friction of pipes